# iOS app - Lite version or paid version

Tags: ios, xcode

In windows phone "App.xaml.cs" file contains the following method to identify whether the app is trial version in Windows Phone app.

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
  var license = new Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation();
   IsTrial = license.IsTrial(); }
```

Here IsTrail is the property which returns true or false. Is there any method is available for iOS to detect the lite or Paid version?

Answer (score 5):

There is no concept of trial in iOS App Store. You submit two different apps with different names - lite/pro etc. Since the apps are completely different binaries, you can simply use compile time preprocessor macros to differentiate between PRO and LITE versions.

Eg, in your PRO target, define `LITE=0`, and in LITE: `LITE=1`, and in code:

```
#if LITE
//do something
#else
//do something else
#endif
```

Just a word of warning: You might want to check Apple guidelines with respect to free/paid apps combo. As @manujmv mentioned, you don't want to use words like "Trial" or "Beta" in your app name. Any app submitted to the App Store should be functionally complete in itself and should be supported without asking user to pay additional $$$ (i.e. no time based expiry).

Comment: This kind of application will be rejected.  You need to do this via In-App Purchasing

Comment: @borrrden what are you talking about, there are several free/pro combos including [Angry Birds Free](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/angry-birds-free/id409807569?mt=8). Using "Trial"/"Beta" leads to rejection.

Comment: thanks.. May i knw where to use this conditions and initialization

Comment: Oh, I got turned around from the OP using the word "trial".  Nevermind me ^^

Comment: @Mar0ux, yes working perfect.Do I need to submit two apps in AppStore?Such that for upgrading, users have to download new version from app store?

Comment: @gobi You need to take a call. There is another alternative - have only one app which contains in app purchase options for premium features. This way user doesn't lose their data (like saved game scores etc) and doesn't have to download the app again.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, from Appstore review guidelines:

```
2.9 Apps that are “beta”, “demo”, “trial”, or “test” versions will be rejected
```